# Elegant way to cut the leading 0's in a String of numbers?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, integer

A number comes in as a string, such as `"000105"`, and I'm trying to find a good way to ignore the leading zeroes. A RegEx comes to mind, but sometimes those can get hard to read. What I do currently is:

```
stack = "000105"               # => "000105"
overflow = stack.to_i.to_s     # => "105"
```

Is there some easier/elegant way to do this? It feels clunky to convert this string to an integer and back to string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
overflow = stack.sub(/^0+/, '')
```

or just `sub!` if a want to change `stack` itself:

```
stack.sub!(/^0+/, '')
```

I would use `sub` instead of `gsub`, because it needs to match only once.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a regex replace using

```
^0+
```

Replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vH0iN5/9

Answer (score 1):

Building on @vks answer you can do something like this in ruby,

```
stack.sub!(/^0+/,'')
```

Comment: What's? the diff between `gsub` and `gsub!`? And is there any function like `sub` in `ruby`, since this won't need to be done globally.

Comment: @AvinashRaj -- `gsub` will not permanently change the object/variable that it's being invoked on. Most of the 'bang' methods that end with the `!` however, will permanently change them. You would use the .gsub when you just wanted to temporarily change things for a computation, but still didn't want to alter your variable itself on a permanent basis.